# Why does my python server save the post request data to the database as "0"?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, sqlalchemy

I am working on a full-stack app( react/flask). I am trying to send form data via POST request from the client, but the data is being saved as "0" in the database. the react code works fine but the sent data is saved as "0". Can you guys please help me with that?

Here is the flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
import os
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow



app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'hi.db')
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'super-secret'  # change this IRL


db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def welcome():
    email = request.form.get('email', False)
    test = List.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if test and request.method =="POST":
        return jsonify(message='This email already exists. Please enter a different email.'), 409
    else:
        name = request.form.get('name', False)
        user = List(name=name, email=email)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify(message="Thank you for Joining my app waiting list. we promise we won't spam your email!"), 201


# database models
class List(db.Model):
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Here is the react code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

export default function Users() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <Form>
        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
          <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control 
            type="email"
            // name= "email" 
            placeholder="Enter email"
            value={email}
            onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
          <Form.Text className="text-muted">
            We'll never share your email with anyone else.
          </Form.Text>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
          <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control 
            type="text"
            // name="name" 
            placeholder="Enter Your Name"
            value={name}
            onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} 
            />
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
      <Button 
        variant="primary" 
        type="submit"
        onClick={async () => {
          const credential = { email, name };
          const response = await fetch("/", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            body: credential
          });

          if (response.ok) {
            console.log("response worked!");
            console.log("body", credential)
          }
        }}>
          Submit
      </Button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is a screenshot from the Db client
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request body is of type JSON but your Content-Type header is set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", so your request body should be FormData: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i don't see that I set the request body to be a type of JSON. are you talking about the flask code or react code? in flask code am getting the form data from the form to my understanding as (request.form.get('email', Flase). in the react code am NOT setting the body to be a JSON object. correct me if iam wrong.Thanks

Comment: When you declare const credential, that is a JS object

Comment: yes the react code and the flask code were out of sync. the backend was expecting a formData data and i was sending a JSON object. so i edit my backend code to accept Json objects (email = request.json['email']) and the frontend to be 
headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(credential)